# What are some elementary differences in the geometry of the 2-dimensional real affine space and the 2-dimensional complex affine space?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm looking for some basic facts about these two spaces to give me some sense of how differently they act. In particular, with respect to the classical Euclidean axioms. If we take a line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ to be a subset that looks like real 2-dimensional plane, what are some differences that arise?

Comment: Which classical Euclidean axioms are you referring to?

Comment: @Somos The axioms described here https://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/euclid.htm

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you think are the differences and which ones you are not sure about?